# Android Project Structure Changed After Gradle Sync

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working with android studio attempting to implement the following github within my own application

https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo

When following the instructions I add the following line to the gradle

compile project(':scanlibrary')

After adding the above i then sync the gradle and the whole project structure changes, to the point where i no longer recognise it

Original Project Structure
[image: Original project structure]

New Project Structure
[image: New Project Structure]

If you havnt gathered i am fairly new to the whole android programming thing

One thought i had was that the git project uses OpenCV and it was related to this, however i have not manually installed OpenCV

Comment: On one of your images it says project with :scanLibrary could not be found in build path of :app, so my que. is have you imported scanlibrary? if so try cleaning & rebuild your project. Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: I've not imported the scan library just yet. In truth I need to figure out how it's done  do you think after I import the scan library that the structure will return to normal?

Comment: Yes the structure will come to normal after you finished importing scan library, if you haven't done it earlier see my answer

Answer (score 2):

You have to import scan library to bring project structure to normal. Follow these steps:

1 - Download zip from [this link](https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo).

2 - Extract it and copy location of scanlibrary project present inside ScanDemoExample. In my case it is like `(D:\Amrit\AndroidScannerDemo-master\AndroidScannerDemo-master\ScanDemoExample\scanlibrary)`.

3 - Now come back to Android Studio, select

> File -> New -> Import Module

and paste copied location path from previous step in **source directory** which will result in **module name** `:scanlibrary`. Click on `Finish` to close the dialog.

4 - Now your project structure will look like image below. (You can view it by selecting File -> Project Structure).
[image: project structure of scan library demo]

5 - Don't forget to add dependency

```
compile project(':scanlibrary')
```

inside **build.gradle** file.

6 - Now your library is ready to use with your project. In case you are facing any errors try **cleaning & rebuilding** your project. And more often errors are **import problem** so try including these imports :

```
import com.scanlibrary.ScanActivity;
import com.scanlibrary.ScanConstants;
```

where **ScanActivity** & **ScanConstants** are classes present inside scanlibrary.

Let me know if you have any doubts. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This looks like exactly what I was looking for. I'll let you know how I get on

Comment: @amrit Pal Singh Ji Thanks for the answer, saved my lot of time.

Comment: Hello @Amrit Pal Singh, can we rename the naming convention of this package 
for example if we want to convert the name of com.scanLibrary.ScanActivity and we want to rename it to beta.scanlibrary.ScanActivity but it is throwing errors for the C++ files not getting changed because of the JNI linkage can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

add this depenedency in build.gradle

implementation 'com.github.neutrinosplatform:scanlibrary:3.3'

and add maven in repositories

maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }